# Derivation of Euler-Lagrange Equations

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differentiation, variational-principle, variational-calculus

I am studying the Euler Lagrange equations and have some problems understanding its derivation.

Consider a path $y(x)$ where a slight deviation  from the path is given by $$Y(x,\epsilon) = y(x) + \epsilon n(x)$$
where $\epsilon$ is a small quantity and $n(x)$ is an arbitrary function.

The integral to minize is the usual $$I=\int^{x_2}_{x_1} \phi\left(x,Y,Y'\right)dx,$$ where $Y'=\dfrac{\partial Y}{\partial x}.$

In the [textbook *A student's guide to lagrangians and hamiltonians* by Hamill](https://www.google.com/search?q=a%20student%27s%20guide%20to%20lagrangians%20and%20hamiltonians%20pdf) (pg 51), to minimize the above integral, the author arrived at the equation

$$\left[\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial Y} - \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial Y'}\right)\right]_{\epsilon=0} = 0.$$
He then proceeded to say that this is equaivalent to requiring that
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} - \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y'}\right) = 0.\tag{2.9}$$

I have trouble seeing why the above last equations are equivalent. How does one show that they are indeed equivalent?

Comment: Crosposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3696446/11127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an application of the chain rule. If $r(a,b)=a+b$, then
$$ \frac{\partial \phi(r(a,b))}{\partial a} = \frac{\partial \phi(r)}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r(a,b)}{\partial a} = \frac{\partial \phi(r)}{\partial r} . $$
Now you can assign $r$ to either $Y$ or $Y'$ and $a$ respectively to $y$ or $y'$ the get the result you are looking for.